# How to create elements and select them on the fly with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chaining

I'm a bit stumped with this. I would like to create some elements (using jQuery), call a function on that wrapped set, and continue this process several times via a chain. For example,

```
$('<div id="xxx"></div>')
  .call_plugin()
  .append('<div id="yyy"></div>')
  .call_plugin()
  .etc...
.end();
```

Where the first call to plugin affects xxx, the second affects yyy, and so forth. But this isn't happening; I think the call_plugin() is being called on the first div (id=xxx) every time. Is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: .append() actually "pastes" yyy insdes xxx, and returns the new xxx. So the second call_plugin affects the new xxx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call jQuery again for other elements to execute certain functions on, and append those with `.append`:

```
$('<div id="xxx"></div>')
  .call_plugin()
  .append(
     $('<div id="yyy"></div>')
     .call_plugin()
  );
```

You can nest them the same way:

```
$('<div id="xxx"></div>')
  .call_plugin()
  .append(
     $('<div id="yyy"></div>')
     .call_plugin()
     .append(
        $('<div id="zzz"></div>')
        .call_plugin()
     )
  );
```

Just don't forget not to put `;`s after the nested `append`s.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('<div id="xxx"></div>')
  .call_plugin()
  .append('<div id="yyy"></div>')
  .find('#yyy') // added this. From now on the current selection is #yyy element
  .call_plugin(); // this will be called on #yyy
```

---

The `.end()` method (*that you use at the end*) is used to end the current selection in a chain if you want to continue with the previous one of the same chain...

In your example

```
$('<div id="xxx"></div>')
  .call_plugin()
  .append('<div id="yyy"></div>')
  .find('#yyy') // added this. From now on the current selection is #yyy element
  .call_plugin() // called on #yyy
  .end() // this returns the selection to be #xxx
  .something()//something else that will be called on #xxx
```

Comment: This was a tough call. I think this answer is simpler, but I just couldn't get it to work. (Doesn't mean it's wrong either!) +1, and thank you for the reply!